# Is "weón" used in Chile and what does it mean?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, chile, insultos

What does "weón" mean? Someone told me that *weon* is used in Chile, but he was not sure what it meant. Could anyone from Chile tell me what this word means? Or is it offensive to call somebody "weón"?

Comment: "El weón weón weón" uses 3 different meanings of weón

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got it! Here in Chile we say more like "güeón" but you could read it in chats as "weón" "wn" (abbreviated) "hueón" "hueon" "weon". Also there is something like "apelativo" which is "aweonao" "aweonado" "agüeonado"; most difficult one to translate. Note that in Chile we abused of this term, calling anything and using with every sentence as the situation could. Examples:

"Hola po weon cómo estay?" (hey dude how are you?)
"Qué pasa aweonao? (what's up dude?) --rude one
"Mira el weón como cruza la calle..." (look at that guy  how cross the street)
Look at this one, very rude and impolite:

"La wea que hizo el weon aweonao" (what a crap did that stupid guy)

Answer (score 10):

**Meanings of *weón* in Chile** (apologies for poor grammar on english keyboard)

*Weón* = dude, bro, man; *Cómo 'tai po weón?*; [*How are you, man?*]

*Weón* = asshole, jerk; *Ese árbitro es un weón*; [*That referee is a jerk*]

*Weá* = a thing; *Estamos al frente de la weá*; [*We're in front of the thing*]

*Puta la Weá* = *screw this shit* [yes, this is rude to say]

*Webiando* = doing something, messing around; *Los chicos estan webiando al frente de la weá*; [*The kids are doing something in front of that thing*]

*Webiar* = to do something (usually annoying,) mess around; *Quítate de webiar, hijo!* [*Son, stop being annoying!*]

Example: My cousin describing the movie "Gravity" to me in Chilean Spanish:

Mira *weón*, habían dos tipos, *weón*, la Sandra Bullock y ese *weón* George Clooney, cachai? Y los dos están allí, *weón*, *webiando* en el espacio, *weón*... Encontré esa *weá* muy fome, *weón*, no me gustó la película...

Comment: Or the classic example: "el weon weon, weon" (the guy is an asshole, dude)

Comment: Also, they all are deformations of "weón" = "huevón", "wea" = "huevada". In some regions of Argentina (Patagonia, Mendoza) you can hear the full versions "huevón" y "huevada".

Answer (score 6):

In Mexico we don't use `weon`/`webon`, instead we use `wey`. `Weon` is the slang for huevon (as explained in previous answers) and it's used mainly in Chile but it's also used in other South American countries like Peru(as far as i know).In Mexico we use `huevon` in specific cases to refer to someone who doesn't work or is just lazy, but as a regular expression we just use `wey`. We either use `wey` to refer to someone in an inoffensive way (with friends just means `buddy` or `dude`) or in some cases it can be taken as a disrespectful word to express someone is stupid or a fool.

Comment: is "heuy" means the same way as "wey"?

Comment: @DerPolyglott33 "heuy" is not even a word in Mexico. I don't know if you are trying to write something else, in that case please check your word and re-write it if needed :)

Comment: Maybe he was trying to write "huey", but that's a very uncommon way to spell "wey". I've seen it some times spelled as "güey" or "guey" (this last one would actually be pronounced without the U, but some keyboards don't allow ü sign so it's common to see in the internet spelled like this)

Answer (score 3):

I think should be `Webón` or `Wevón` para referirse a `Huevón`, quiere decir de huevos(testículos) grandes, se le dice así a los vagos o alguien que molesta mucho.

Los chilenos y los mexicanos además lo usan mucho para hablarse entre amigos, por ejemplo:

¿Qué es de tu vida `Wevón`? => ¿Cómo estás bro/dude?

Comment: Podrian explicar el voto negativo?

Comment: Debe haber alguien a quien le molestan los testículos. +1

Comment: When my chilean friends used that word, they pronounce it so fast that they really seemed to say "Güeón" instead of "Güevón".

Comment: You got it! Here in Chile we say more like "güeón" but you could read it in chats as "weón" "wn" (abbreviated) "hueón" "hueon" "weon". Note that in Chile we abused of this term, calling anything and using in every sentence as the situation could. Examples:

Comment: Creo que estás parcialmente equivocado, en Chile no se dice "huevón" como en tu ejemplo, se dice "hueón".

Answer (score 3):

I live in Chile as an exchange student. This word appears in *every sentence* from any young Chilean. No exaggeration. Probably it comes from huevón but here it's written as weón in *every* situation(SMS, Whatsapp, FB etc.) It's *totally different* from its Mexican sense and it's *of utmost importance* not to confuse the two. At the very least if a Chilean calls you "weón" don't get angry XD. You should probably even be happy because they treat you as a close friend.

"weón" mostly means "dude, bro" in a casual and intimate sense. It's true it can also mean "moron"/"stupid person" but that usage is much much less common.

Also one says "wea" which means "cosa"(thing). "Qué wea" means "what?".

Comment: right, but be careful, "weon" as "moron" is not much much less common; the meaning has to be extracted from the context: no more solution. As an example, if you drive a car in Chile, and you miss a traffic light that could have cause an accident, for sure the affected will say you something like "fijate po aweonao": which means something like "be careful stupid moron". In Chile is one the most difficult words. Even for me as a Chilean is difficult sometimes to extract from the context.

Comment: Almost equivalent of the Argentine "boludo", "boló".

Answer (score 3):

Most importantly: **None of these words should be written with W**. It should be "huevón" (even if sometimes the v is not pronounced). As it has been explained, in Mexico it means lazy. "Güey" usually means stupid. Depending on the tone, none of these should be considered an insult (but they can be, of course).

Comment: I believe this question is about "weón/hueón" and how is used in Chile. Probably "huevón" as used in Mexico but is not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 2):

First, you can write it as hueón, huevón, güeón, güevón or weón, it doesn't matter (but we mostly use "wn" or "weón"). This is used in Chile and was propagated among other countries in South America due to the internet and social networks.

Meanings:

Weón
1) dude, bro, man
2) a person, a man, an unknown
3) jerk, asshole, stupid

Weá
1) a thing in general
2) an annoying thing or situation, something that is unpleasant, crap, shit

(if you see, it is a "normal" or "neutral" way as a first meaning, so you don't need to be upset if someone tells you "weón")

So, for example, if you heard "oye weón, el otro día estaba en la estación de metro y un weón casi se mata, quería saltar a la weá donde pasan los metros... y un weón que estaba al lado mío, se reía en vez de preocuparse... fue desagradable la wea", it would be something like "hey dude, the other day I was in the subway station and a man almost kills himself, he wanted to jump to the thing where the trains travel... and a jerk beside me was laughing instead of being worried... the situation was unpleasant"

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: Can you explain where did you get this information? `This is used in Chile and was propagated among other countries in South America due to the internet and social networks.` It looks fake to me.

Answer (score 1):

Could be use as an offense or to reffer a person or simply as an equivalent of "dude" or "bro", it depends of the context.

Answer (score 1):

Correct word is "huevón" and it is accepted by RAE (http://dle.rae.es/?id=KlzpOYH)

The fact is that when spoken, normally it is pronounced fast as "weón" (güeón, or whatever). When written, it could be as "wn"

I know that in Mexico, this means a lazy person, but in Chile it is normally used as the meaning of "pal" used by all people colloquially. In that context, this is not an insult but something like a pet word. In other context, it can mean a foolish or idiot guy.

Comment: To use the word "correct" is not very nice when you are talking about colloquial, spoken language. I also don't believe that the RAE (Real academia española) is the best authority for defining the way people speak, specially for those countries who don't follow a king (hence the word "real"). It should only be taken as a reference.

Comment: And a correction to your answer, in Chile the word is `hueón/weón` for either spoken and written language. People will never write "huevón". They could, however, abbreviate it as "wn".

Comment: https://images.app.goo.gl/9fo73JeZL1LneS9M8